# What would be an appropriate syntax for selecting a radio button on a website using VBA?

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Totally new to this and would appreciate any help regarding this. I have gotten my program to open the website and navigate, however I am stuck on the part that involves choosing a radio button. [medical literature website](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=osteonecrosis)

The source code for the `"File"` radio button is as follows:

```
 <input type="radio" name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.SendTo" sid="1" value="File" id="dest_File">
```

[Website layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DmC7.png)

My VBA Code is:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Search_PubMedandCochrane()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed"

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Debug.Print IE.LocationName, IE.LocationURL

    IE.Document.forms("EntrezForm").elements("term").Value = Range("B4")

    IE.Document.forms("EntrezForm").elements("search").Click
    While IE.Busy
    Wend
    IE.Document.querySelector("[sourcecontent='send_to_menu']").Click

End Sub
```

My question is:
1) I would like a syntax which would choose the `"file"` radio button, select the Medline format under format drop down, then click the `"create file"` button at the bottom. I would really appreciate if I can get some help with the syntax for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked at least 3 questions there (with I suspect a 4th you would later ask). You should really only ask one per question. The very last part of saving to desktop you can research as is covered extensively on StackOverflow. I have put in a simply SendKeys in case that works but if you end up needing something more complex like FindWindow or looping windows that is a question in itself and one, as I mentioned, that is very easy to research.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SearchPubMedandCochrane()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=osteonecrosis"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document

            .querySelector("[sourcecontent='send_to_menu']").Click

            While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            .querySelector("#dest_File").Click  '<== File radio button

            While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            .querySelector("option[value=medline]").Selected = True  '<= medLine option

            While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            .querySelector("[cmd=File]").Click  '<== generate file

            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
            Application.SendKeys "%{S}", True

        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```